# 403 Response when I use requests to make a post request

Tags: django, post, python-requests, http-status-code-403, csrf-token

My core code is as follows:

```py
import requests
url='https://www.xxxx.top'  #for example
data=dict()
session = requests.session()
session.get(url)
token = session.cookies.get('csrftoken')
data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = token
res = session.post(url=url, data=data, headers=session.headers, cookies=session.cookies)
print(res)
# <Response [403]>
```

The variable `url` is my own website, which is based on Django.  I know I can use `@csrf_exempt` to disable CSRF, but I don't want to do that.
However, it return 403 response when I use `requests` to make a post request. I wish someone could tell me what was wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  In this case, just add `Referer` to headers

```py
import requests
url='https://www.xxxx.top'  #for example
data=dict()
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                'Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36','Referer':self.url}
session.get(url)
token = session.cookies.get('csrftoken')
data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = token
res = session.post(url=url, data=data, headers=session.headers, cookies=session.cookies)
print(res)
```